# Protected 18650 batteries shut down after I introduce a capacitor to the circuit, why?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, protection

I have a 24V audio amplifier that is powered by 8 packs of 6x protected 18650 batteries connected in series to produce 24V, and then all the packs are connected in parallel.

The amplifier powers a subwoofer and a pair of speakers. The issue was that when subwoofer kicks a deep note, the system just cuts out.

I introduced 2x47000uf capacitors to the circuit in parallel. Problem I have now, is that the batteries just shut down. I tried it with just one capacitor, and then it worked.

I'm guessing the capacitors drain the batteries too fast and they just switch off.

Is there anything I can add to the circuit to prevent this?
Perhaps a resistor? What rating?

Comment: Inrush current!

Comment: Perhaps a 300W light bulb to charge up the cap

Comment: @winny My thoughts exactly. Solution?

Comment: If the Caps have an ESR of 100 mOhms then the peak current is 24/0.1=240 A  So choose any light bulb in series to connect then keep it charged up always.  Define what causes "System cuts out"  Low batt voltage will not be corrected by adding caps

Comment: Show battery measurements, Amp specs and Speaker impedance.

Comment: You could probably add a MOSFET with an RC on the gate. As to the details, it depends on what  your peak and average load currents are.

Comment: What is the peak power of your amplifier?

Answer (score 5):

It is due to high inrush current in to the system.

The batteries shutdown due to over current. I think you are exceeding the rated current of the protection circuit.

Add an [NTC thermistor](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/products/protection/current/ntc-limiter/technote/apn-ntc-limiter.html) to limit the inrush current. This is a simple and off the shelf option.

Comment: Any idea at all what specification NTC Thermistor should I use for the battery pack I described?

Comment: @Mladen Depends on your battery and ESR. None of which you have provided details for. Find out from the datasheet and set it up in your simulator.

Comment: what winny is saying is true. with out details of battery and the protetcion cirucit it is not possible.

Comment: @winny so it would be something that would limit the flow of electricity from the battery to the capacitors under 16 amps @ about 25v. I appreciate what you guys are saying, but I'm a beginner

Comment: How about using an inductor instead and building a proper LC filter?

Comment: @SimonRichter Sure, but the C is already there and the L would be prohibitively large.

Comment: An NTC thermistor is not appropriate for this application. It would drop excessive voltage during operation. A resistor that is shunted by a really is the most practical approach. This approach used in EVs for charing the capacitors in the motor controller.

Comment: Could someone give me a straightforward answer to what I should buy? Links would be great too :D I'm literally not studying to become an electrical engineer, I just wanna make my community sound system work properly.