# What can I add to a DC circuit, to limit the voltage to 24V and current to 16 amps?

Tags: voltage, current, dc, 24v

I have a battery pack that can put out around 25V and 20 amps, but it needs to be limited to 24V and 16 amps.

Update:

This is a follow-up to my question from yesterday: [Protected 18650 batteries shut down after I introduce a capacitor to the circuit, why?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/441449/protected-18650-batteries-shut-down-after-i-introduce-a-capacitor-to-the-circuit)

I have a battery pack made of 18650 batteries that each have a protection circuit. When I add some large capacitors to the circuit, I assume that they drain too much power from batteries, making those batteries to shut down immediatelly after I flip the switch. So that's my issue

Comment: You need a regulator with current limiting, but you give so little information. A battery packs terminal voltage will reduce as the SOC reduces …..Do you need regulated 24V even when the battery voltage drops?

Comment: no, I just need to make sure it doesn't go over 24v. I got capacitors that drain so much when connected that protection boards on the batteries shut the batteries down.

Comment: A 16 A fuse solves the current aspect of question posed. You need to edit it and state the real problem you are trying to solve. What have you got that's rated at 24 V that can't tolerate 25 V? Why can't you add a soft start for the capacitor charge on power-up? (That's what VSDs do, for example.)

Comment: @Transistor I have a battery pack made of 18650 batteries that each have a protection circuit. When I add some large capacitors to the circuit, I assume that they drain too much power from batteries, making those batteries to shut down immediatelly after I flip the switch. So that's my issue

Comment: @Mladen, you didn't explain why 25 V is a problem or what your load is.